# Confusion on Voltage across a battery

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, batteries

If I have a battery that is 0.1m in length, with the positive and negative terminals situated at the top and bottom, and I am trying to calculate the voltage (electric potential difference, Vdelta = Vfinal - Vinital) for a test charge that goes from the negative terminal to positive terminal (with respect to the positive terminal as the "source charge"), what value do I use for **r** in Vfinal (V = kQ/r)? I'm assuming I would use 0.1m for **r** in Vinital since the test charge starts at the negative terminal (0.1m away from the "Source charge"), but my assumption was to use 0 for **r** in Vfinal since the test charge would be going to the positive terminal (the source charge), but this would yield infinity volts?

Comment: V = kQ/r is the potential due to a single point charge. I don't think you can usefully apply it to a battery in the way you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You pick a starting point, be it top or bottom.

You mark it as 0v. Then you move to whatever direction you want, for example to the opposite pole of the battery, and mark the difference between these two points as delta. And distance is the distance you passed doing so.